# MvvmCross cannot find override method for mapping view model to view

Tags: view, xamarin, mapping, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Has the `Setup` class methods or hierarchy changed? I cannot seem to find a method called `GetViewModelViewLookup` to override in the Setup class

I am trying to map a view to a different view model. I am using MvvmCross 3.5.1

I am trying the following

```
protected override IDictionary<Type, Type> GetViewModelViewLookup()
```

but it tells me there is not a method named this to override. I am trying to follow the example on the old MvvmCross blog [link](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/overriding-view-lookup-convention-used.html)

Any ideas?

Update * it looks as if the base class used to be `MvxBaseSetup` which contained `GetViewModelToViewLookup`, but now it is just `MvxSetup` which does not contain it.

So how do I override the viewmodel to view mapping now?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the **naming scheme**, the function to overwrite is `CreateViewToViewModelNaming`

```cs
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    public Setup(Context applicationContext) : base(applicationContext)
    {
    }

    protected override IMvxNameMapping CreateViewToViewModelNaming()
    {
        return new ReverseViewModelNaming();
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new Core.App();
    }

    protected override IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace()
    {
        return new DebugTrace();
    }
}

class ReverseViewModelNaming : IMvxNameMapping
{
    public string Map(string inputName)
    {
        // MyView is presented by the view model named weiVyM (how useful :P)
        return string.Join("", inputName.Reverse());
    }
}
```

If you want to change the **mapping**, the function to overwrite is `InitializeViewLookup`. If you just want to add some extra mappings, call `base.InitializeViewLookup()`.

```cs
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    public Setup(Context applicationContext) : base(applicationContext)
    {
    }

    protected override void InitializeViewLookup()
    {
        var registry = new Dictionary<Type, Type>()
        {
            { typeof(FirstViewModel), typeof(FirstActivity) }, 
            { typeof(HomeViewModel), typeof(HomeActivity) } ,
            { typeof(DetailViewModel), typeof(DetailActivity) }, 
            { typeof(UploadViewModel), typeof(UploadActivity) }
        };
        var container = Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewsContainer>();
        container.AddAll(registry);
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new Core.App();
    }

    protected override IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace()
    {
        return new DebugTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sven, my problem is that I want the same view model mapped to multiple views. This breaks the uniqueness of the dictionary key. For Xamarin iOS is there anyway to do this via another mechanism?

Comment: It is possible, but than you need another approach. But to find the correct approach, you have to tell more about your requirements. Based on wich conditions do you want to decide to view ViewA or ViewB when navigating to ViewModelAB ?

Comment: I have a scenario where I have a summary view, and when clicking on it I want to show the detailed view. I want both to use the same view model, as the summary view data is just a subset of the details view data

Comment: The simplest solution for this one case would be to inherit a "empty" `DetailViewModel` from your `SummaryViewModel` to establish a one to one connection. There are more complicated solutions. But I think it would be too much effort for just few cases.